# "use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer" not working

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am trying to make a form that can contact me via email with PHP. I am new to PHP so after watching a couple of videos I am making with PHPMailer. After I downloaded the zip file from GitHub and installing composer and these things, the code shows some errors. When I declare "use\PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer," it says **Unexpected, 'Unknown'**.

**My code is this**

```
<?PHP
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
//Server settings
$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
$mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
$mail->Host       = 'smtp.example.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username   = 'user@example.com';                     //SMTP username
$mail->Password   = 'secret';                               //SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
$mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

//Recipients
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
$mail->addAddress('joe@example.net', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient
$mail->addAddress('ellen@example.com');               //Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

//Attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         //Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    //Optional name

//Content
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

$mail->send();
echo 'Message has been sent';
 } catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
?>
```

The code is from the GitHub page I just copied and pasted it to test it. I edited the JSON file and all of them but it doesn't work.
Appreciate the help from everyone. Thank you

Comment: so far you are showing us a single file that is using PSR4, this wont work unless you require the composer autoload file. link the github project, I can help you fix this but also make sure you have composer installed.

Comment: @MichaelMano I have installed the composer and did all the things that were in this link: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that you are running PHP that’s older than version 5.3, which is when namespaces and the use statement were introduced. Upgrade your PHP - any new development should be using 8.0.

Answer (score 0):

Move your autoload to the top of the file, using PSR4 before the autoload is in wont work.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
...
```

Though you should really keep your autoloader in a seperate file. e.g. a `index.php` and create a Mailer class of your own.

How you would go about doing this would be adding an autoload to your `composer.json`

```
{
    "name": "acme/app",
    "type": "project",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "some name",
            "email": "email@example.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "phpmailer/phpmailer": "^6.4"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Acme\\": "src/"}
    }
}
```

Creating a `src` folder with a file named `App.php`

```
<?php
namespace Acme;

class App
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        echo 'works'; // Do what ever you want. 
    }
}
```

Create a `index.php` in the root

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

Acme\App::boot();
```

then run composer install or composer du and run `php index.php` and your set.

Comment: It is not true that you must put the autoloader first. Use statements are local aliases and have no effect on loading classes.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen cases where the classes were placed inside a PHP function. That will throw an error.

From the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer):

> **These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function**
> use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
> use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
> use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;